# I want to search each row in each worksheet to find text and then return the whole row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with around 100 worksheets containing a 3 letter code as the title. I want to loop through each worksheet, and within each worksheet, loop through column 2 ("b") and see if the cells in any given row contain the word "Total" if they do, then skip to next row, if they do not copy that row until column 11 and paste it on a designated worksheet. This doesn't seem to output anything an I am wondering where I went wrong? Edited code below, no more error messages.

```
Sub Charges()

Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, rw As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets
Set a = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set b = wb("Output")



    For Each ws In wb
        rw = 2
        If Len(ws.Name) = 3 Then
            For Each r In a.Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
                If InStr(1, r.Value, "Total") < 0 Then
                    r = r + 1
                    With a
                        .Range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 11)).Copy b.Cells(r, 2)
                    End With
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Can someone help? Lmk if you need clarification.

Comment: I think it should be `r.Value` not `cell.Value` in the instr.

Comment: What's `cell`? Your loop is `For Each r`... and that also means that `Cells(r, 2)` and `Cells(r, 11)` are problematic - maybe `r.Row` instead of `r`.

Comment: And what is `rw=rw+1` trying to do?

Comment: Got it, I changed it to R and that fixed the bug, thank you, but it still does not do what I want it to. It doesn't output anything. I think it may be an issue with how I phrased my if instr statement. Any thought?

Comment: `<1` is probably not what you want with `InStr`. `>0` most likely.

Comment: Are you certain what `ActiveSheet` actually is when you assign it to `a`? Probably better to set it explicitly to the proper sheet.

Comment: The sheet changes as it loops through every worksheet so it has to change. Anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have references to sheets that are not what you want.

```
Sub Charges()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim b As Worksheet
    Set b = wb.worksheets("Output")

    Dim rw As Long
    rw = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If Len(ws.Name) = 3 Then
            Dim r As Range
            For Each r In ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Cells
                If InStr(1, r.Value, "Total") < 1 Then
                    With ws
                        .Range(.Cells(r.Row, 2), .Cells(r.Row, 11)).Copy b.Cells(rw, 2)
                        rw = rw + 1
                    End With
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This code errors Object does not support property as  Set b = wb("Output")

Comment: That Worked. Thank you so much. Can I ask though, is this copying the entire row or just until the column that the current region (Column 11) ends on?

Comment: it is copying everything between column 2 and column 11 as per your code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again @scott Craner